# How do I overload my instantiated EdgeDriver() with DriverDirectory, DriverService and Options. Or how do I apply all three to my driver?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

How do I overload my edge driver() with DriverDirectory, DriverService and Options. Or how do I apply all three to my driver?

So I'm doing this:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");

EdgeDriverService myDriverService = new EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
myDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(Setup.DirectoryPath, options); //Want to apply myDriverService
//in here

//how would I apply a myDriverService to the method, there's no overload for Driver Directory,
// options and Driver Service, only Driver Directory and Options?

//I want:
EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(Setup.DirectoryPath, myDriverService, options);
```

but that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the EdgeDriver source code, it will already have a constructor that looks something like:

```
public EdgeDriver(Path directorypath, EdgeOptions options)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It is simple enough to add another constructor such as:

```
public EdgeDriver(Path directorypath, EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then you can instantiate it with whichever overload you choose:

Alternatively, you could add a public settable Service property so you can set the service with:

```
edgeDriver.Service = myDriverService;
```

or a method that sets the service you provide:

```
edgeDriver.SetService(myDriverService);
```